# React Native: view not reacting at state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my Tinder like react-native app I have a huge list of tags that people can add to their profile when they click on a tag, I want the tags the user adds to be a different color however, the background color is not changing... only time everything looks as it should is when I change the view/code and the component refreshes, then the colored tags appear.

This is my code:

```
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

const addItem = (id) =>
    {
        
        console.log(id);
        if(selectedItems.includes(id))
        {
            let index = selectedItems.findIndex(interest => interest == id);
            if(index > -1)
            {
                let selectedInterests = selectedItems;
                selectedInterests.splice(index, 1)
                setSelectedItems(selectedInterests);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(selectedItems.length < 10)
            {
                let selectedInterests = selectedItems;
                selectedInterests.push(id);
                setSelectedItems(selectedInterests);
            }
        }
    };


{root.userStore.tags.map((item,index) => {return (
                        <Text key={item.id} onPress={ ()=>{ addItem(item.id) } } style={{ fontSize:17,padding:6,paddingLeft:10,paddingRight:10, ...selectedItems.includes(item.id) ? { color:'white', borderColor:'#E13545',backgroundColor:'#E13545' } : { color:'rgb(100,100,100)',borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',backgroundColor:'white' },borderRadius:35,borderWidth:1,margin:5 }}>{I18n.t(item.title)}</Text>
                        )
                    })}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something does not appear to be correct with your destructuring, to use multiple styles you can try using a styles array, I did not get a chance to run this but should work. You can check documentation of the style array [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style), you may also consider using a flatlist for this if possible

```js
{
  root.userStore.tags.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Text
        key={item.id}
        onPress={() => {
          addItem(item.id);
        }}
        style={[
          {
            fontSize: 17,
            padding: 6,
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingRight: 10,

            borderRadius: 35,
            borderWidth: 1,
            margin: 5,
          },
          selectedItems.includes(item.id)
            ? {
                color: "white",
                borderColor: "#E13545",
                backgroundColor: "#E13545",
              }
            : {
                color: "rgb(100,100,100)",
                borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
                backgroundColor: "white",
              },
        ]}
      >
        {I18n.t(item.title)}
      </Text>
    );
  });
```